# How to differentiate between <Select /> components if "onChange" does't provide e.target.name?

Tags: html, reactjs, antd

I have multiple `select` components in my form. 
How do I differentiate between them if I can't get access to `e.target.name`

```
onChange={this.handleSelect}   
//onChange passes just a value to handleSelect.
```

Here is the reference of `select` component
https://ant.design/components/select/

I don't want to create multiple `handleSelectField` for each select component.

Comment: You can just have `state = { firstSelect: '', secondSelect: '' }` and then have two separate functions. E.g. `onChange={(value) => setState({ firstSelect: value })}` and `onChange={(value) => setState({ secondSelect: value })}`

Comment: Yes, I see that, but this is what I'm saying: "I don't want to create multiple handleSelectFieldfor each select component"

Comment: Yes, I saw that, but you can't distinguish between the two without separate handlers. You could do something like `onChange={(value) => this.myHandler(value, 'firstSelect')}` if you absolutely don't want to create multiple handlers, but it's more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: This looks good. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with creating separate event handlers, but if you absolutely don't want to you can send which value to update with the value to the event handler.

**Example**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { firstSelect: null, secondSelect: null };

  handleChange = (value, field) => {
    this.setState({ [field]: value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Select onChange={value => this.handleChange(value, "firstSelect")} />
        <Select onChange={value => this.handleChange(value, "secondSelect")} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```